# Converting json dictionary to spark dataframe by having keys as columns

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, databricks

Is it possible to convert a dictionary into a dataframe by having the keys as columns with the values beneath?

I have this result set from api as a dictionary:

```
{
'information': [{
    'created': '2020-10-26T00:00:00+00:00',
    'title': 'Random1',
    'published': 'YES',
}, {
    'created': '2020-11-06T00:00:00+00:00',
    'title': 'Random2',
    'published': 'YES',
}, {
    'created': '2020-10-27T00:00:00+00:00',
    'title': 'Random3',
    'published': 'YES',
}, {
    'created': '2020-10-29T00:00:00+00:00',
    'title': 'Random4',
    'published': 'YES',
}]
}
```

If I convert this to a dataframe like this:

```
json_rdd=sc.parallelize([data_dict['information']])
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(json_rdd)
spark_df.createOrReplaceTempView("data_df");
```

This gives me columns listed as _1, _2, _3,_4 with the data still showing as objects within them.

Is it possible to have the data_df (converted dataframe) show the columns as created, title, published and have the values within the corresponding columns as flat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use the dictionary to create dataframe no need to covert it to rdd.

```
arr = your_dict_here
spark.createDataFrame(arr['information']).show()
```

Output:

```
+--------------------+---------+-------+
|             created|published|  title|
+--------------------+---------+-------+
|2020-10-26T00:00:...|      YES|Random1|
|2020-11-06T00:00:...|      YES|Random2|
|2020-10-27T00:00:...|      YES|Random3|
|2020-10-29T00:00:...|      YES|Random4|
+--------------------+---------+-------+
```